# How to profile HTTP calls made by PHP

Tags: php, profiling

When rendering some pages there are multiple calls using file_get_contents, drupal_http_request and CURL.  I would like to be able to profile the page and pinpoint where in code these external service calls are being made and what the URIs are.

xhprof does not appear to provide this functionality.  xhprof will tell me that file_get_contents was called, but it does not tell me where in code it was called or what URI was called.

filtering tcpdump will tell me what URI gets called, but it doesn't tell me where in PHP it was called.

Comment: Dont you like to use any HTTP-proxy tools?